# Specific exceptions are not shown when using async/await and Task.Run

Tags: c#, io, async-await, task

I have a webpage with a list of recipes. In my code, I loop through the page and download each recipe. Here is a pseudo code of what I am doing :

```
//This is the Recipe class
//The constructor accepts a link to the recipe
//This method scrapes the recipe
public Task ScrapeAsync(){
    return Task.Run(async () => {
        string WebPage;
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(link);
        request.Method = "GET";
        using (WebResponse response = await request.GetResponseAsync())
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())) {
            WebPage = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
        }
        //Non - async code here which is used to scrape the webpage
    }
}
```

I used Task.Run because there are both async and blocking code in the Method.

```
//This is the RecipePage class
//This method scrapes the page
public Task GetRecipeListAsync(){
    return Task.Run(async () => {
        //I get the page using WebRequest and WebResponse in the same way as above

        //Non - async/blocking code here which scrapes the page and finds links to recipes. I do await Recipe.ScrapeAsync() somewhere here.
        //And I add the recipe objects to a public list in this class
    }
}
```

In the form, it loops through a list of pages and do `await RecipePage.GetRecipeList()` and other things.
Here's where the for loop is:

```
private async void go_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
    for (int i = (int)startingPageNUD.Value; i <= (int)finishingPageNUD.Value; ++i) {
        RecipePage page = new RecipePage(page + i);
        await page.GetRecipeListAsync();
        //Some other code here
    }
}
```

My problem is that whenever an exception happens in the `ScrapeAsync` method, Visual Studio 2013 points to `Application.Run(new Form1())`

```
static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }
```

and tells me that `Reflection.TargetInvocationException` has occured. It does not show the actual exception in my code. For example, if I get a `NullReferenceException` in the code, it does not show that.
Because of this, I am having to write both async and non-async code and use non-async code to debug. Is there any way to solve this?
I have another question too. Am I using async/await and Task in the correct way?

Comment: How the code that calls `GetRecipeList` looks like?

Comment: I know exceptions like this to happen, if the thrown exception has nowhere to go. This may happen in case it is thrown from a `await` inside a function that returns `void` instead of `Task`. If your recipe loading loop in such a function?

Comment: No. the loop is just in an async event handler.

Comment: Can you add the function header of that even handler to your example? The thing is: Where does the exception end up? Every await will re-throw the exception that is thrown inside the `Task` that is awaited.

Comment: Ok I have added the event handler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay. Thanks to your edits I now can answer.

Your problem is this function:

```
private async void go_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
    for (int i = (int)startingPageNUD.Value; i <= (int)finishingPageNUD.Value; ++i) {
        RecipePage page = new RecipePage(page + i);
        await page.GetRecipeListAsync();
        //Some other code here
    }
}
```

The issue is that the function returns to what ever calls it once it reaches the `await`. Now if `page.GetRecipeListAsync();` throws a exception, this exception is thrown inside the continuation handler. This handler is executed in the task queue of your UI. A exception thrown there crashes the task loop of your UI and this has all sorts of funny effects including strange exceptions.

In a `async void` function you should **always** handle any incoming exceptions by wrapping all code inside into a `try`…`catch`. If you crash the application if a exception occurs there or not is yours to decide.

The general way the things work is that any exception thrown inside a `Task` and by extend in a `async` function are thrown again by the `await`. But the `async void` functions are not `await`ed anywhere, so that does not work.

Regarding the usage of the `async`. I don't think you need to wrap every function into a `Task` but you can do that. Usually you don't need to force it into the background like this.

Answer (score 2):

> Am I using async/await and Task in the correct way?

Pretty close. I don't see a need for `Task.Run` in this scenario (it should only be used to move CPU-intensive operations off the UI thread, and HTML scraping is usually fast enough to stay on the UI without any adverse effects).

The other recommendation I'd make is to have `async Task` methods *return* values as much as possible, instead of modifying member variables as side effects. In your case, consider having `ScrapeAsync` return its own list instead of updating a shared list, and having the calling code do the list merging.

Regarding your exception, `TargetInvocationException` will have an `InnerException` with the details. Exceptions in `async void` event handlers are managed in practically the same say as exceptions in regular `void` event handlers: if one escapes the event handler, then it goes to the application main loop. If you don't want this, you'll have to catch it (for both synchronous and asynchronous handlers).

Answer (score 1):

Encapsulate the getRecipeList code inside a try/catch.

In the catch code, get exception message and stack trace and assign them to variable(s) of Recipe class that you will test/display in your main thread when action is completed.

```
private string TheException = "" ;

public Task GetRecipeListAsync()
{
  TheException = "" ;
  Task result = Task.Run(async () => 
  {
    try 
    {  
      //I get the page using WebRequest and WebResponse in the same way as above
      ...
     }
     catch (Exception Ex)  
  }
  if (TheException!="") MessageBox.show(TheException) ; 
  // or Throw an exception with
  return result ; 
}
```

you may also test "TheExceptio" in the GoClick procedure.

Comment: Can you elaborate please? I am not so good with exception throwing and re-throwing stuff